# Write to file without overwriting with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want a logger for my project. Everytime I call myConsole.log it overwrites the existing log. what can i do that the it just write it in the next line and not delete everything

```
const fs = require('fs');
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./output.log'));
myConsole.log(var)
myConsole.log(var2)
myConsole.log(var3)
```

Comment: You will want to set the flags option to r+ the default is w.

Answer (score 2):

I'd reccomend looking at [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), which is a package that does great logging.

But with your code, you need to add the `a` (append) flag to your fs writer so it writes properly rather than overwriting (default flag is `w`), like so:

```
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./output.log', { flags: 'a' }));
```

See docs on [createwritestream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) and [system flags](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `{ flags: 'a'}` as options argument to the [createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) call.

This flag will open the file for appending instead of overwriting